# Backtracking crossword algorithm in c

Tags: c, backtracking

So i made a backtracking algorithm in c, where i get a txt file filled with words in each line and another txt file just has coordinates for the black squares of a square crossword. I know my implementation is extremelly simple, but i just want to have the barebones algorithm, to make it much faster later on with constraint satisfaction, forward checking etc.

However i have no idea how to get the basic code to work without segmentation faults and wrong solutions! Ant advice would be very helpful!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 150000
#define MAX_DIMENSION 200
#define MAX_BLACK_SQUARES 250


int is_valid_word(char *word, int dimension, char crossword[MAX_DIMENSION][MAX_DIMENSION])
{
int i, j, k;
int word_length = strlen(word);

// check if word is too long
if (word_length > dimension)
{
    return 0;
}

// check if word overlaps existing letters
for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
    {
        if (crossword[i][j] != '_')
        {
            for (k = 0; k < word_length; k++)
            {
                if ((i + k < dimension && crossword[i + k][j] != '_' && crossword[i +   k][j] != word[k]) ||
                    (j + k < dimension && crossword[i][j + k] != '_' && crossword[i][j + k] != word[k]))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    return 1;
}

int solve_crossword(int dimension, char crossword[MAX_DIMENSION][MAX_DIMENSION], char           words[MAX_WORDS][30], int num_words, int word_index)
{
    int i, j, k;
    if (word_index >= num_words)
    {
    // all words have been placed, so return true
    return 1;
}
// try placing the current word horizontally
for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < dimension - strlen(words[word_index]); j++)
    {
        if (crossword[i][j] != '#')
        {
            // try placing the word here
            int is_valid = 1;
            for (k = 0; k < strlen(words[word_index]); k++)
            {
                if (crossword[i][j + k] != '_' && crossword[i][j + k] != words[word_index][k])
                {
                    is_valid = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (is_valid)
            {
                // place the word
                for (k = 0; k < strlen(words[word_index]); k++)
                {
                    crossword[i][j + k] = words[word_index][k];
                }
                // recursive call to place the next word
                if (solve_crossword(dimension, crossword, words, num_words, word_index + 1))
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                // backtrack by removing the word
                for (k = 0; k < strlen(words[word_index]); k++)
                {
                    crossword[i][j + k] = '_';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// try placing the current word vertically
for (i = 0; i < dimension - strlen(words[word_index]); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
    {
        if (crossword[i][j] != '#')
        {
            // try placing the word here
            int is_valid = 1;
            for (k = 0; k < strlen(words[word_index]); k++)
            {
                if (crossword[i + k][j] != '_' && crossword[i + k][j] != words[word_index][k])
                {
                    is_valid = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (is_valid)
            {
                // place the word
                for (k = 0; k < strlen(words[word_index]); k++)
                {
                    crossword[i + k][j] = words[word_index][k];
                }
                // recursive call to place the next word
                if (solve_crossword(dimension, crossword, words, num_words,word_index + 1))
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                // backtrack by removing the word
                for (k = 0; k < strlen(words[word_index]); k++)
                {
                    crossword[i + k][j] = '_';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// if we get here, we were unable to place the word in either direction
return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // open dictionary file
FILE *dict_file = fopen("dicts/EvenMoreWords.txt", "r");
if (dict_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open dict.txt\n");
    return 1;
}

// read dictionary into array
char words[MAX_WORDS][30];
int num_words = 0;
char buffer[30];
while (fgets(buffer, 30, dict_file) != NULL)
{
    int word_length = strlen(buffer);
    if (buffer[word_length - 1] == '\n')
    {
        buffer[word_length - 1] = '\0';
    }
    strcpy(words[num_words], buffer);
    num_words++;
}
fclose(dict_file);

// open crossword file
FILE *crossword_file = fopen("crosswords/c1.txt", "r");
if (crossword_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open crossword.txt\n");
    return 1;
}

// read dimensions and black squares
int dimension, i, j, width, height;
fscanf(crossword_file, "%d", &dimension);


// initialize crossword
char crossword[MAX_DIMENSION][MAX_DIMENSION];
while (fscanf(crossword_file, "%d %d", &width, &height) != EOF)
{
    crossword[width - 1][height - 1] = '#';
}
printf("\n\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
    {
        if (crossword[i][j] != '#')
        {
            crossword[i][j] = '_';
            printf("%c  ", crossword[i][j]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c  ", crossword[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n\n\n");

// solve crossword
if (solve_crossword(dimension, crossword, words, num_words, 0))
{
    // print solution
    for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", crossword[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Unable to find a solution\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Use a debugger to locate the seg faults. Then, work with a small grid to get solutions, and bigger grids to look at efficiency. In that order.

Comment: This code appears to be happy to place a 3 letter word in a space with 5 blanks... That's not how crossword puzzles work. And, the local array `crossword` starts life uninitialised. This is unpredictable.

Comment: I tried out your code on my Linux machine with test words from a small crossword puzzle.  In my case, I did not get a segment fault, but the program seemed to be caught in an endless loop.  To be brief after a bit of debugging, I increased the size of the length value test for the horizontal and vertical word placement test as "for (j = 0; j < dimension - strlen(words[word_index]) + 1; j++)" and then the program appeared to work.  As noted, it would be best to debug the program, but you might want to give that a try.